# Flamerobin doesn't connect to Firebird database (msg: -902 isc_attach_database failed)

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, flamerobin

I'm studying Firebird 2.5 with FlameRobin 0.9, installed on a VM Virtualbox (with O.S. Win7 32bit PRO). The .fdb files are on the same disk of the Firebird machine and the FlameRobin program. The machine is not embedded and run as Superserver.

With FlameRobin I've created more than one.FDB file, created tables, triggers, generators, etc: all works fine.

I use Delphi7 to create executables that utilize the .fdb file.
Yesterday, during a proof, Delphi arise an error of "out of system resource": disconnect .FDB in Flamerobin, close Flamerobin (quit), close the VM; re-open the VM, re-open FlameRobin, re-register the .fdb... error:

> IBPP:: SQLException; Context: Database::Connect; Message: SC_ATTACH_DATABASE
>   failed; SQL message: -902 unsuccessful execution caused by a system error
>   that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements. Unable to 
>   complete network request to host LocalHost.

On the VM there is no antivirus and Windows firewall is disabled (on the host machine, Avast Internet Security is running).

- I've haven't varied any parameters, all is developed as described.
- In the .conf file, the Firebird machine can connect to all.
- If I use a program compiled with Delphi, to insert or update some record in a Firebird table, all works fine, but FlameRobin doesn't want connect to Fdb.
- In FlameRobin, the item "user manager" lists SYSDBA-masterkey and another user added by me 10 days ago.

On Internet, I've not found cases of the kind. Does it depend on Win7? And how? Can someone help me, to continue the work? Thanks for any suggestion that can be useful to understand the problem.

Comment: Is there anything in the `firebird.log`? Can you create a new database in FlameRobin? Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: (SOLVED) @Mark  NO, I've not tried to create a new database. YES, I've changed the localhost to 127.0.0.1. This morning. I've tried to stop the guardian and restart it: magic! FlameRobin works ok! Perhaps, the message "out of system resource" was by the O.S, not  by Delphi. I would been able to think it without bothering the community. before. Thanks for interest. Cordially.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the guardian at all on recent Windows versions: install it as a service without guardian: the Windows service management will do the job of the guardian. But in any case, if that solved the problem, it suggests that you might not have rebooted your VM but just suspended the VM with Firebird already down and then unsuspended it with the Firebird process still down.

Comment: He, I don't remember if I've reboot the VM or not, and surely you are right! Now, I must understand. Firebird runs as a service on Win7, because I've pointed out "this" during the installation. The Guardian is an utility (with a least interface) included in Firebird installation pacKet and installed automatically by the installer. This utility appears in the Control Panel and it gives the possibility to stop / to start the service. Is this right? Why  must not the  Guardian be installed? Does it interfere with something? The same operations can be made, however, accessing the Win7' services.

Comment: The Guardian will work, but it is entirely unnecessary on Windows. That the Firebird installer still installs it is mostly out of conservative approach to change.

Comment: Ok, received. Thanks of all.